# Docusaurus strips some attributes from inline SVGs; need ID for accessibility

Tags: svg, docusaurus

I'm using inline SVGs like this:

Content of `icon-checkmark.svg`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 46 46"><title id="myTitleID">An accessible title</title><path {…} /></svg>
```

Import & inline:

```
import CheckmarkSvg from '/img/site-components/icon-checkmark.svg';

<CheckmarkSvg role="image" aria-labelledby="myTitleID" className="myClass" />
```

But Docusaurus strips the title's `ID` attribute from the rendered SVG.

Is there a workaround for this? Without it, the title is not accessible in some browsers.

Comment: It's what I suspected: There is a dependency in `@docusaurus/core` for `@svgr/webpack`, which in turn ultimately loads [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo). This one will strip "unused" ids from SVG files unless the module `cleanupIds` is **deactivated**. Good look finding where this config is supposed to go.

Comment: Good to know. Turns out it was easier (and a good learning opportunity) to create a custom component and inline the SVGs that way.

Post your comment as an answer & I'll mark it as correct.